# Неправильное отображение времени

Tags: ios, objective-c

Код на `Objective-C`, но все же, присутствует баг с временем, есть некий datepicker, допустимое время которое можно выбрать должно быть с 9 утра до 3 ночи следующего дня

Сейчас условие работает не правильно, если я выберу дату сегодня в 21, то выдаст ошибку о том, что заведение работает с 9 утра до 3 ночи, можете помочь пофиксить условие?

```
- (BOOL)isWorkingYesterday:(NSDate *)date {
    if (date.timeIntervalSince1970 == 0.0) {
        date = [NSDate date];
    }

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSCalendarUnit units = (NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute);
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter defaultTimeFormatter];

    NSDate *yesterday = [NSDate yesterdayDateForDate:date];

    NSString *yesterdayStartString = [self startForDate:yesterday];
    NSString *yesterdaEndString = [self endForDate:yesterday];
    NSString *startDayString = @"00:00";
    NSString *orderDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSDate *yesterdayStart = [formatter dateFromString:yesterdayStartString];
    NSDate *yesterdayEnd = [formatter dateFromString:yesterdaEndString];
    NSDate *startDay = [formatter dateFromString:startDayString];
    NSDate *orderDate = [formatter dateFromString:orderDateString];

    BOOL isInYesterdayRange = (orderDate.timeIntervalSince1970 >= startDay.timeIntervalSince1970
                               && orderDate.timeIntervalSince1970 < yesterdayEnd.timeIntervalSince1970);

    if (yesterdayStart.timeIntervalSince1970 >= yesterdayEnd.timeIntervalSince1970 && isInYesterdayRange) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;

}
```

Вызывается так

```
if (![order.restaurant isWorkingYesterday:order.deliveryDate]) {
            NSString *start = [order.restaurant startForDate:order.deliveryDate];
            NSString *finish = [order.restaurant endForDate:order.deliveryDate];
            // вывод ошибки с временем, о том, что заведение работает с 9 до 3 ночи 
            message = RESTAURANT_IN_NON_WORKING_HOURS(start, finish);
        }
```

Comment: По тому коду, который есть, вроде все правильно. Точно правильные данные вводите, не путая нигде дни? (например 3 часа ночи это следующий день) Еще проверка у вас в конце странная: `yesterdayStart.timeIntervalSince1970 >= yesterdayEnd.timeIntervalSince1970`, что она делает? Хотя там все равно &&, по идее не должно влиять на правильный результат.

Answer (score 0):

В целом, если отбросить лишние преобразования, то у вас метод должен выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
@implementation DateManager

- (BOOL)isWorkingStartingFrom:(NSDate *) startDate andEndDate: (NSDate*) endDate andOrderDate: (NSDate*) orderDate {
    BOOL checkWorkTimeIsInvalid = startDate.timeIntervalSince1970 >= endDate.timeIntervalSince1970;

    if (checkWorkTimeIsInvalid) {
        return NO; // Время начала должно быть меньше, чем время конца
    }

    BOOL isInWorkRange = (orderDate.timeIntervalSince1970 >= startDate.timeIntervalSince1970
                               && orderDate.timeIntervalSince1970 < endDate.timeIntervalSince1970); // тут предельно просто, заказ должен помещаться между началом и концом

    if (isInWorkRange) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;

}
```

Для проверки можно написать юнит-тест:

(Это Swift)

```
func testDateManager() {
        let dateManager = DateManager()

        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.year = 2019
        dateComponents.month = 7
        dateComponents.day = 31
        dateComponents.hour = 9 // условно вчера в 9 утра начали
        dateComponents.minute = 00

        // Create date from components
        let userCalendar = Calendar.current // user calendar
        let startDate = userCalendar.date(from: dateComponents)

        dateComponents.hour = 21 // заказ был в 21 вечера вчера

        let orderDate = userCalendar.date(from: dateComponents)

        dateComponents.day = 1 // заканчиваем на следующий день в 3 часа
        dateComponents.month = 8
        dateComponents.hour = 3

        let endDate = userCalendar.date(from: dateComponents)

        if (startDate != nil && endDate != nil && orderDate != nil) {
            if (dateManager.isWorkingStarting(from: startDate!, andEnd: endDate!, andOrder: orderDate!)) {
                XCTAssert(true) // попадем вот сюда
            }
            else {
                XCTFail()
            }
        }
        else {
            XCTFail()
        }
    }
```